# C++, pre-processor statement

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Can someone explain what does this statement do?

```
#define CONST_SIG (void (*) () ) 1
```

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble understanding? Do you know what `#define` does, in general?

Comment: On the whole, it would be advisable for there to be an extra set of parentheses around the whole expression, though the cast has a sufficiently high precedence that it is probably safe as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement defines `CONST_SIG` to be `1` cast into a pointer to a function that gets no parameters and returns `void`. This *may* be useful if you have a pointer to a function and you perhaps test it for truthness, then `CONST_SIG` will be true.

You can try the `cdecl` program, which is available in many linux distributions, for "English translation" of C declarations. Example output in this instance:

```
cdecl> explain (void (*) () )
cast unknown_name into pointer to function returning void
```

Side-note: The reason it says "unknown_name" is because our pointer has no name. To name it, for example, "p", would look like this: `(void (*p) () )`.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass CONST_SIG to a function which expects a function pointer and treats a value of 1 as a special value for this function pointer.